# Why ModuleNotFoundError occurs when trying to run script with PyPy3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cpython, pypy

I have a Python script which runs perfectly with CPython (under virtualenv), unfortunately throws ModuleNotFoundError error when I run it with PyPy3 (under virtualenv).

My package is `parser` and I import `Analyze` with `from parser.Analyze import Analyze`. There is `parser` directory under the same directory with my script. And parser directory has `__init__.py` file in it too.

Should I do something special for PyPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On both PyPy and CPython `parser` is a built-in module. Can you see if the problem is that the built-in is masking your package? You can rename it to something like `myparser`. PyPy tracks issues at https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues or you can reach out on IRC at #pypy